# Visual Studio 2022, Can I control how the immediate values are generated for arm64 compilation?

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, arm64, immediate-operand

When I have the following code:

```
int value2 = 0x11223344;
```

The VS2022 compiler (arm64) generates:

```
StarFunction PROC 

...
ldr         w8,|value_label|
...
...
...

ret 

|value_label|
    DCD         0x11223344 

ENDP
```

As you can see, the value 0x11223344 is generated as "data" at the end of the function.

Is there any way to have some control on that so it generates instead:

```
mov  w8, 0x1122
movk w8, 0x3344, lsl 16
```

I cannot use compiler optimizations as I need to have control over the generated
code to patch specific code sequences. With compiler optimizations, I loose that control.

I have tried different compiler optimization switches but some of them have no effect and
other more aggressive optimizations even remove the declaration of "0x11223344" and directly
use it in code afterwards.

Summing up, can I "force" somehow the compiler to avoid that "data" mixed with code for immediate values in arm64?

Comment: Have you tried writing it out, something like:  `int a = 0x1122;  a = (a << 16) + 0x3344;`?

Comment: Thanks @ErikEidt, but it generates more code than expected:  ```mov  w8,#0x1122;  str w8,[sp,#8]; ldr  w8,[sp,#8];  lsl  w9,w8,#0x10; mov  w8,#0x3344; add  w8,w9,w8; str w8,[sp,#8] ```

Comment: If you use global variables to store intermediate values then you force the compiler to generate code for lines even with optimizations on. Try assigning 0x11223344 to a global variable and compile with -O2.

Answer (score 0):

I found that declaring the local variables with "volatile" such as:

```
void MyFunction()
{
   volatile int i = 0x1123344;

   // some code here
}
```

And also compiling with `/Ox`, makes the compiler generate the wanted `mov Wn, imm16_low; movk Wn, imm16_high, lsl 16` at the expected location where it was declared.

Here is a full example (compiled with `/Ox`)

```
int TestFunction()
{
    volatile int a = 0x11223344;
    volatile int b = 0x77887788;
    return 0;
}
```

Generates:

```
|int TestFunction(void)| PROC                  
|$LN6|
        sub         sp,sp,#0x10
        mov         w8,#0x3344
        movk        w8,#0x1122,lsl #0x10
        str         w8,[sp]
        mov         w8,#0x7788
        movk        w8,#0x7788,lsl #0x10
        str         w8,[sp]
        mov         w0,#0
        add         sp,sp,#0x10
        ret

        ENDP  ; |int TestFunction(void)|, TestFunction
```

Comment: With optimization enabled, it uses `mov`/`movk` to put 32-bit constants into registers in general, including for `return x + 0x1123344;` .  (https://godbolt.org/z/K1jM4bo9M ).  But with optimization disabled, it loads from memory (PC-relative from nearby data it looks like), even if it's going to assign the result to a `volatile`.  So it seems `volatile` is irrelevant to how it materializes constants, only optimization level.

Comment: Of course, if you let it optimize, it might constant-propagate the constant into a different value for the asm, so maybe `volatile int modifiable_a = 0x11223344;` / `int a = modifiable_a;` so you aren't forcing the inefficiency of `volatile` on every later use in the function.  (Seems like it might be easier and more efficient to just have a global variable, or maybe volatile static, for external modification with a symbol attached to the value.  Then it would just be one adrp/ldr.)